# How to choose invoices and make payment in payment form odoo14

Tags: odoo, accounting

n v14, I want to make invoices payment in payment form by choosing invoices.  In v13, already have invoice_ids field and I changed to readonly to 0 and can make payment. But in v14, there is no invoice_ids field.So I create this but how can I do that?I share my some code

```html
invoice_ids = fields.Many2many('account.move', 'account_invoice_payment_rel', 'payment_id', 'invoice_id', string="Invoices", copy=False,
                                   help="""Technical field containing the invoice for which the payment has been generated.
                                   This does not especially correspond to the invoices reconciled with the payment,
                                   as it can have been generated first, and reconciled later""")
```

My view is

```html
record id="view_account_payment_form_inherit_payment" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">view.account.payment.form.inherit.payment</field>
                <field name="model">account.payment</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_payment_form"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <xpath expr="//group" position="after">
                    <group invisible="context.get('active_model') == 'account.move'">
                      <field name="invoice_ids" attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_id', '=', False)]}"   readonly="1" domain="[('partner_id','child_of',partner_id),('state','=','posted'),('payment_state','=','not_paid')]" >
                          
                          <tree>
                              <field name="partner_id"/>
                              <field name="name"/>
                              <field name="amount_residual"/>
                              <field name="state"/>
                          </tree>
                      </field>
                    </group>
                    <xpath/>
                    </field>
                    </record/>
```

Comment: you found sollution?

Comment: @Bashir. I found solution

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @Bashir. I shared my code.Hope this work for you. But you need to write xml file for inoices id.

Comment: @Bashir. It works for you?

Comment: I followed this sollution https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-get-all-related-account-moves-to-the-payment-in-odoo-14-179646

Answer (score 0):

```
class AccountPayment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment'
    invoice_ids = fields.Many2many('account.move', 'account_invoice_payment_rel', 'payment_id', 'invoice_id', string="Invoices", copy=False,
                                   help="""Technical field containing the invoice for which the payment has been generated.
                                   This does not especially correspond to the invoices reconciled with the payment,
                                   as it can have been generated first, and reconciled later""")

    def action_view_move(self):
        return {
            'name': _('Journal Entries'),
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'account.move',
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'domain': [('id', 'in', self.mapped('move_id').ids)],
            'context': {
                'journal_id': self.journal_id.id,
            }
        }

    @api.depends('amount')
    def _compute_amount_untaxed(self):
        rec = []
        untaxed_amount = 0.0
        for payment in self:
            if payment.invoice_ids:
                for invoice in payment.invoice_ids:
                    # untaxed_amount += invoice.amount_untaxed_signed
                    # if invoice.move_type == 'out_invoice':
                    #     untaxed_amount += invoice.amount_untaxed
                    # elif invoice.move_type == 'out_refund':
                    #     untaxed_amount -= invoice.amount_untaxed

                    if invoice.move_type in ['out_invoice','in_refund']:
                        untaxed_amount += invoice.amount_untaxed
                    elif invoice.move_type in ['out_refund','in_invoice']:
                        untaxed_amount -= invoice.amount_untaxed
            payment.amount_untaxed = abs(untaxed_amount)
        return rec
    @api.onchange('invoice_ids')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        logging.info("======================= compute_amount =================")
        logging.info("===== invoice.")      
        total = 0.0
        if self.invoice_ids:
            for invoice in self.invoice_ids:
                if invoice.move_type in ['out_invoice','in_refund']:
                    total += invoice.amount_total_signed
                elif invoice.move_type in ['out_refund','in_invoice']:
                    total -= invoice.amount_total_signed
                self.amount = total

   
    
    def action_post(self):
        res = super(AccountPayment, self).action_post()
        # logging.info("=========================== action_post start here")
        # logging.info(res)
        # logging.info(self)
        for payment_res in self:
            # logging.info("-------- payment_res")
            # logging.info(payment_res)
            # logging.info(payment_res.amount)
            # logging.info(payment_res.invoice_ids)
  
            if payment_res.invoice_ids:
                moves_to_reconcile = []
                # for move in payment_res.move_id.line_ids:
                #     logging.info("============ before_moves_to_reconcile =================")
                #     logging.info(partner_account)
                #     logging.info(payment_res)
                #     logging.info(payment_res.display_name)
                #     logging.info(payment_res.move_id)
                #     logging.info(payment_res.move_id.display_name)
                #     logging.info(move)
                #     logging.info(move.display_name)
                #     logging.info(move.account_id)
                #     logging.info(move.account_id.display_name)
                for move in payment_res.move_id.line_ids:
                    # logging.info("**************************")
                    # logging.info(move.display_name)
                    # logging.info(move.account_id.id)
                    # logging.info(move.account_id.display_name)
                    if move.account_id.id == partner_account:
                        moves_to_reconcile = []
                        moves_to_reconcile.append(move.id)
                        # logging.info("============ moves_to_reconcile1 =================")
                        # logging.info(moves_to_reconcile)
                for invoice in payment_res.invoice_ids:
                    for move in invoice.line_ids:
                        # logging.info("------------------------------------")
                        # logging.info(partner_account)
                        # logging.info(move.account_id.id)
                        # logging.info("------------------------------------")
                        if move.account_id.id == partner_account:
                            moves_to_reconcile.append(move.id)
                # if moves_to_reconcile:
                    # logging.info("============ moves_to_reconcile2 =================")
                    # logging.info(moves_to_reconcile)
                move_lines = self.env['account.move.line'].search([('id','in',moves_to_reconcile)])
                move_lines.reconcile()
        # logging.info("=========================== action_post end here")
        return res
```